# What is the runnable object passed in Java thread pool RejectedExecutionHandler

Tags: java, threadpool

I have [thread pool with a RejectedExecutionHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#ThreadPoolExecutor%28int,%20int,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,%20java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue,%20java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory,%20java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionHandler%29) like this and a Runnable task.

```
sExecutorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor( ...    new MyRejectionHandler() );

interface MyTask extends Runnable { ... }

class MyTaskImpl implements MyTask { ...}
```

i execute a task like this

```
   sExecutorService.submit(myTask);
```

in rejectedExecution case i was hoping to get hold of rejected Runnable (ie MyTask) and set some field in it marking it as rejected. But i am not able to cast it to MyTask. 
So what exactly is the  runnable passed t o rejectedExecution ?  It appears not MyTask i submitted . And how can i get hold of the rejected task in RejectedExecutionHandler.

```
public class MyRejectionHandler implements RejectedExecutionHandler{  
   public void rejectedExecution(Runnable runnable, ThreadPoolExecutor executor)  {
    MyTask myTask = (MyTask) runnable; // exception
    myTask.doSomething();
   }
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.concurrent.FutureTask cannot be cast to MyTask
```

Comment: Please refer this article . [http://bobah.net/d4d/source-code/misc/thread-pool-executor-example-j2ee](http://bobah.net/d4d/source-code/misc/thread-pool-executor-example-j2ee)

Comment: This link gives an example of ThreadPoolExecutor and RejectionHandler. But it doesnt explain anything about and neither can one infer anything about the very specific question i asked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is when you submit task with submit method TreadPoolExecutor (actually AbstractExecutorService) wrap it to FutureTask. After that you receive FutureTask not your Runnable. You can call execute not submit:

```
sExecutorService.execute(yourTask);
```

I don't think there is a way to get your task from FutureTask. You can only call run for it. So if you want to call submit and you need to call run - just do not convert to MyTask:

```
FutureTask myTask = (FutureTask) runnable;
myTask.run();
Object result = myTask.get();
```

Other way if you want to access you MyTask object can be creating of MyFutureTask extends FutureTask, that will allow get your object:

```
public MyFutureTask<V> extends FutureTask<V> {

    private Runnable myTask;

    public MyFutureTask(Runnable runnable, V result) {
        super(runnable, result);
        this.myTask = runnable;
    }

    public Runnable getMyTask() {
        return myTask;
    }        
}
```

Also you need to extends ThreadPoolExecutor and redefine newTaskFor method that is responsible for Runnable to FutureTask wraping:

```
public class MyThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {

    @Override
    protected <T> RunnableFuture<T> newTaskFor(Runnable runnable, T value) {
        return new MyFutureTask(task, value);            
    }
}
```

After that you can use MyThreadPoolExecutor as a ThreadPoolExecutor and in rejecting task processing:

```
MyFutureTask myFutureTask = (MyFutureTask) runnable;
MyTask myTask = (MyTask) myFutureTask.getMyTask();
// Now you can do what you want with you task:
myTask.doSomthing();
```

Comment: thanks. I am using submit() because i want the Future return value. I submit many tasks as a batch and sometimes i need to go back and cancel all submit ted tasks in batch from "main" thread.  If i use execute() i dont get the Future return values to cancel() them later.

Comment: Edit my answer with second part - for FutureTask and submit call.

Comment: Ok, i dont want to run it. I just want to set some field in it marking it as rejected. That is why i was looking for getting MyTask instance. I guess it may not be possible to get MyTask instance,  from your answer. (I will explore some other way). Thanks

Comment: Edit my answer to show one of posible ways to get your task from FutureTask. Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks. For my usecase i solved it using the fact that the submit() will throw the RejectedExecutionException when task is rejected. I just catch it and handle the task. While creating threadpool use `ThreadPoolExecutor.AbortPolicy()` which will simply rethrow the exception.